# python:"Unable to use a tty",when code :os.system(kubectl exec -it podname -n namespace -- /bin/bash)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Environment: Windows 10

Code:

`os.system("kubectl exec -it riot-rms-7f454d68f4-66d6j  -n riot -- /bin/bash ")`

error info:

> Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file

Comment: Hi cuang753 welcome to SO. Yes, beacuse `-t` is short for `--tty` which means to allocate a tty but there is no such thing when run under `os.system`; you can go ahead and remove the `-i` from that `exec`, too, because there's no stdin for `os.system`, either. To quote someone very famous: "you're holding it wrong"

Comment: I'm not sure what your higher-level goal here is, but the overall approach seems problematic: this syntax suggests you're trying to `kubectl exec` only one pod in a Deployment, so your various replicas will be out of sync, and any change you make this way will get lost if the specific Pod gets deleted (possibly outside your control).  You'll also have trouble interacting with the shell that gets launched this way.  What's your actual goal, and can you do it without `kubectl exec` (and ideally without the `os` or `subprocess` modules)?